# What is the space complexity str.count()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, space-complexity

What is the space complexity of using the built-in Python string method `.count()`?

Eg: `inputstring.count(x)`.

Comment: Would you expect it to be anything other than constant, or at worst linear on the needle length?

Comment: I would expect it to be constant. But i guess i need to check implementation to confirm that.

Comment: The CPython code for `str.count` is in [`PyUnicode_Count`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L9371). In modern versions of Python, this dispatches to one of `asciilib_count`, `ucs1lib_count`, `ucs2lib_count`, or `ucs4lib_count` depending on how the haystrack string is stored, but ultimately they all come down to the generic [`STRINGLIB(count)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/count.h#L7) code, which just calls [`FASTSEARCH`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h#L163).

Answer (score 2):

The CPython code for `str.count` is in [`PyUnicode_Count`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L9371). In modern versions of Python, this dispatches to one of `asciilib_count`, `ucs1lib_count`, `ucs2lib_count`, or `ucs4lib_count` depending on how the haystrack string is stored, but ultimately they all come down to the generic [`STRINGLIB(count)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/count.h#L7) code, which just calls [`FASTSEARCH`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h#L163).

If you look at the top of that last source file:

```
/* fast search/count implementation, based on a mix between boyer-
   moore and horspool, with a few more bells and whistles on the top.
   for some more background, see: http://effbot.org/zone/stringlib.htm */
```

For single-character needles, it's basically just doing a `strchr`. For non-tiny needles, it does, as implied, build a Boyer-Moore delta table, which involves a bloom filter and some other stuff that's linearly proportional to the size of the needle, plus some other stuff that's constant. But there's nothing proportional to the size of the haystack.

So, whether you call that constant or linear depends on whether you consider the size of the needle an input or a constant.

Comment: So if we consider size of needle as constant, it is safe to say space complexity is constant

Comment: The comment in the source *says* "create compressed boyer-moore delta 1 table", but it's so (lossily) compressed, it's really not much of a table. There's only one skip value instead of the entire table of skip values real Boyer-Moore uses, [because the original stringlib author wanted to avoid dynamic allocation](http://effbot.org/zone/stringlib.htm)

Comment: This means the space complexity of FASTSEARCH is constant, not proportional to the size of the needle, sacrificing the benefits of a full table to save dynamic allocation costs. (I'm not sure what allocation might be going on elsewhere, though; it seems like allocation might be needed to convert the inputs to a common format.)

Comment: Ah, [here's that allocation I was looking for](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.0/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L9403). When the haystack is stored in a format with more bytes per character than the needle, the needle is copied to make the formats match. (When the needle has more bytes per character than the haystack, it can't be in the haystack. Unicode objects in "canonical" representation are always supposed to use the most efficient format their contents allow, so in this case, the needle must contain a higher-valued character than any haystack character.)